# What is the most efficient way of converting all "HH:MM:SS" to seconds and invalid strings to NaT?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a DataFrame storing marathon segment splits (5K, 10K, ...) and identifiers (age, gender, country) as columns and individuals as rows. Each cell for a marathon segment split column may contain either a string in "HH:MM:SS" format or a "-" (to represent that the marathon segment split data for that individual is invalid or does not exist).

What is the most efficient way of converting all "-" to NaT and "HH:MM:SS" to seconds?

Here is some sample data:

```
      Age M/F Country       5K  ...      15K      20K     Half Official Time
2323   38   M     CHI  0:21:40  ...  1:03:54  1:25:07  1:29:43       2:58:47
2324   23   M     USA  0:21:26  ...  1:02:09  1:22:17  1:26:34       2:58:47
2325   36   M     USA  0:21:08  ...  1:02:55  1:23:56  1:28:30       2:58:47
2326   37   M     POL  0:20:34  ...  1:02:03  1:22:52  1:27:24       2:58:47
2327   32   M     DEN        -  ...  1:03:02  1:24:06  1:28:39       2:58:48
```

I've referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28850135/15936471) but my data has already been read from a CSV file (I do not want to change how I read in the CSV file) and seems to not be able to accept "-". Conversion to DateTime objects with the following code:

```
df.loc[:, "5K":] = df.loc[:, "5K":].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%H:%M:%S", errors="coerce")
```

causes each cell for a marathon segment split column to be prefixed with "1900-01-01".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're measuring runtimes, a more appropriate conversion function might be [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df.loc[:, "5K":].apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='S', errors='coerce'))
```

Two things to keep in mind here:

For durations, rather than points on the timeline, `pd.to_timedelta` is conceptually more appropriate than [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I get this error when running your code: "TypeError: arg must be a string, timedelta, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series".

Comment: @Ben.T. I just realized that. My mistake.

Comment: I'm assuming I should iterate through each column name from "5K" to Official Time and apply your code for each column name?

Comment: @StackOverflow. My mistake. Fixed now

Comment: The above code seems to convert everything into Timedelta objects; is there anyway to extract the number of seconds from these Timedelta objects for each cell?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Just in case someone needs it, here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457238/15936471